# XCode/CLANG error "ignoring file file ... was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)"

Tags: xcode, clang

The unsupported file format is listed as ( 0x09 0x2E 0x73 0x65 0x63 0x74 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x09 0x5F 0x5F 0x54 0x45 0x58 0x54 )

The file in question are ALL c++ files in the project.

I have an Xcode project that had been compiling fine, and all of a sudden it's getting this error.  Many other people have observed this, but I have not seen any solutions I can use.   I don't know what that hex value means, but other folks seem to think it is a 386 compile.  However, the only valid architectures I have in my project are x86-64, and this is being produced in the x86-64 directory.

Debugging this for me is impossible because it's in XCode, and so all the options are essentially hidden.  Can anyone here suggest XCode options that might effect this, so I can check them?

Bear in mind, it worked before, and I've changed no settings.  I've tried all the suggestions - doing clean builds, leaving XCode, etc, but no change.

On a broader note, I've found that XCode versions 8 and newer are almost unusably brittle - change one setting and your project may never work again.  Probably not true for masters working at Apple, but I'm trying to use XCode as a vanilla compiler IDE.

Any help is appreciated.  Only other option is building new project from scratch.

UPDATE:  For practical reasons, I have created a fresh project, imported all the source files, and it works fine.  But I've kept the old project around, because I'd love to find out why things like this keep happening - what their cause might be.  So I'm still very interested in any thoughts out there.  Thanks. :)

Second update that might shed some light on the issue:  Using the new project that compiles without error under both XCode and AppCode, I tried to compile it on a single command line (no intermediate object files) using Clang, and in the command line I got the same "architecture not recognized" error.   Maybe this is actually a Clang problem?  Why would a compiler create a binary it can't use?  This is also interesting because any of you can try this easily for any simpler project that has all the code in a single directory. [EDIT] OK, that was a red herring because I used clang instead of clang++ - thanks to the other slash dotters who caught that.  But this does show one possibility - if a c++ file is for some reason interpreted as c this error can be produced.

Comment: You are using source code control, aren't you? In that case you should have no problem. But if you "change a single setting and your project may never work again", then maybe you are not.

Comment: Ahhh - an excellent idea.  I hadn't been using source code control on the makefile.  That will indeed make my life easier. :)